# Юзернеймы в TeleBot

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать массив из first_name всех пользователей в чате в pyTelegramBotApi?

Answer (score 0):

Телеграм не хранит данные пользователей, которые присоединились к боту. Зато вы можете сами сохранять результаты (к примеру `chat_id`, или тот же `first_name`)
Советую хранить именно в базе данных, так как используя списки/множества/словари - вы потеряете данные, как только бот будет перезапущен. Для простых проектов могу посоветовать `SQLite`. Но если вам нужен именно пример со списками, тогда посмотрите на код ниже:

```
import telebot

users = []
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    if message.from_user.first_name not in users:
        users.append(message.from_user.first_name) 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello')


bot.polling()
```

Но думаю, вы понимаете, что в этом нет смысла, так как у двух разных юзеров может быть одно и тоже имя. Поэтому лучше, например, записывать в списки `chat_id`. А еще лучше использовать словарь, если вам не нужна база данных.